# Adding CSV to ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, csv, d3.js

I am trying to create a basic **d3.js** chart by using Visual Studio 2013 and a **csv** file.
This is the first time I am playing with Visual Studio and not able to understand the reason for **data binding** not happening. after running the following code, I am getting no result. I believe its because the **csv or json** file should be in same folder. but even after that I am not getting desired results.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> D3 Tutorial</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">


 </head>
<body>
<script>

    d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data) { 

        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height",500)

        canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.age * 50;})
                    .attr("height" , 50)
                    .attr("y", function (d , i) { return i * 50 })
                    .attr("fill", "blue")
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please find below the screen shot of my Solution explorer

[image: Solution Explorer - Visual Studio 2013]

Also **mydata.csv**

"name","age"

"Maria",30

"Fred",50

"Francis",12

**Error**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mydata.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mydata.csv'.

Comment: Open the JavaScript debugger and see if you are getting a 404 error.

Comment: @jwize There is no problem with javascript debugger as all the associated js files loaded successfully.

Comment: @jwize Is talking about the developer tools. Is there a 404 error when d3 is trying to pull down the csv file. Use the tools to see where it tried to access it from. You'll quickly be able to determine what's wrong. This is trivial debugging skills...

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Thanks for the hint, I am getting following Error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mydata.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null  

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mydata.csv'.

Comment: It worked finally. Can any of you please write an answer so I can close the question. thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a local file (`"mydata.csv"`) via JavaScript, which is restricted in most modern browsers for security reasons. For your script to work, you need to load your page via a web server. You can either upload your files to a remote server, or host one on your local machine for development.